# Random Sampling and Probability

Tags: probability

What are the possible statistical/mathematical approaches to address the below question?

Assume we have 40millions records and X of them may contain a specific word (e.g.,” dance”). We randomly select 25millons records from the 40millions (a random sampling without replacement). What is the probability of appearing some or all of the X records in the new population? OR how small would X get when it comes to the smaller group of 25m? (what proportion of X would appear in the new population n?)

Comment: Binomial distribution

Answer (score 0):

Let the number of records be $N$, $X$ of them contain the key word: "dance". The probability of choosing an element with the key word is $\approx\frac X N.$ If we randomly select $M$ records then we can model the result with a binomial distribution of parameters $\frac X N$ and $M$. So the probability that the key element appears exactly $n$ times is

$$\approx{M\choose n}\left(\frac X N\right)^n\left(1-\frac X N\right)^{M-n}.$$

The probability that we get all of the key records is

$$\approx {M\choose X}\left(\frac X N\right)^X\left(1-\frac X N\right)^{{25 \ 000\ 000}-X}=$$
$$={{25\ 000\ 000}\choose X}\left(\frac X {50\ 000\ 000}\right)^X\left(1-\frac X {50\ 000\ 000}\right)^{M-X}.$$

If $X=833492$ the the probability sought for is

$$\approx{{25\ 000\ 000}\choose 833492}\left(\frac {833492} {50\ 000\ 000}\right)^{833492}\left(1-\frac {833\ 492}{50\ 000\ 000}\right)^{25\ 000\ 000-{833492}}=$$
$$=1.53079381000316881862094682562175963748630038461450 × 10^{-71462},$$
quite small.

---

Otherwise, by common sense, the expected number of key records in $25000000$ samples $$\frac X{40000000}\times{25000000}.$$

If $X=833792$ then the same is

$$\frac {833492}{40000000}\times{25000000}=520932.5$$

Comment: Thanks. In cases that the size of the population is much larger than the size of the sample, binomial distribution works since the events are independent. Here, I think, this is not the case. Because we don’t put the records back in the pile, the probability of picking up another record and having it be our KEYWORD is now less than before. The successive observations are not independent here. How I should deal with this?

Comment: In the case of such hoge samples, why would yoe care for non replacement? But if you whish I could show the same thing on a small sized sample.

Comment: the reason for non replacement is that in our problem, a record cannot be chosen twice. Sure, it would be a huge help.